# PDF file is always corrupt when saving a binary string as pdf in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdf

I have a bank of pdfs stored as binary in an mssql database. I get the binary string for the pdf returned to php from the mssql database and then pass it to the browser by modifying the headers. The browser then prompts to download the pdf but nothing will open it and says the file is damaged.

I have the basic header implementation as below

```
header ("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=apdf.pdf");
echo $return['Standard_BIN'];
```

Comment: Maybe `$return['Standard_BIN']` contains the data in an encoded form (like base64). How was it saved to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure will have to check with db admin. I know it is an encoded pdf, wasn't under the impression the string was also encoded though.

Comment: What's the exact contents of the generated PDF? Maybe there's some error message sneaking in. Use a text content-type and look for error messages/warnings and a proper PDF header (`%PDF` (hex `25 50 44 46`))

Comment: ok, I changed it to text and opened in txt program. I'll not put the contents here but ive uploaded the txt file to mnwade.co.uk/apdf44.txt there is a mention of pdf in there and looks ok for the first part but then goes a bit crazy after that

Comment: that link doesnt work, wordpress htaccess screwy. this one does https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3435192/apdf44.text

Comment: Well, it should have something like "%%EOF" in the end. I'm trying to find out why the output is incomplete too.